# syntax for attribute type of an img src file in DTD

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt, dtd

When I validate my DTD file, I get this error --> Attribute `type` must be declared for element type `profile`.
How should I edit my DTD file to remove this error?

External DTD

```
!ELEMENT profile ANY
```

XML file

```
<profile type="jpeg">C:\Users\username\Desktop\image3.jpg</profile>
```

XSL file

```
<td rowspan="6" align="left" style="color:#C0C0C0;"> <img src="{profile}" />
```

I had to remove the tags just for it to display on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare attributes in the DTD as:

```
<!ELEMENT  profile       (#PCDATA)*                 >
<!ATTLIST  profile
             type        CDATA            #IMPLIED  >
```